# Return value from a function over SSH gets cropped

Tags: bash, function, ssh

From Server A I want to grep couple lines from a logfile on Server B with a certain watermark.

The logfile contains at least 3 lines with the matched watermark

```
..
13:20 - xxx - line 1
[empty line]
13:20 - xxx - line 2
13:20 - xxx - line 3
..
```

The function which going to be SSH-ed:

```
function functssh {
  grep $time $logfile
}
```

Main (from Server A):

```
RESULT=$(ssh@serverB "$(typeset -f); functssh $time $filename" 2>/dev/null)

echo $RESULT
```

Gives this output:

```
13:20 - xxx - line 2
13:20 - xxx - line 3
```

Line 1 is missing! I have no idea why does it get cropped.

Comment: Make sure what you posted is exactly what you're doing - there's a syntax error above. Also you should quote all variables here, especially `echo "$RESULT"`.

Comment: You actually solved my problem with pointing out the missing quotes on $RESULT :)